Understanding this code to truncate the SVD
In Brunton's and Kutz's data-driven science and engineering book, page $19$, is a description of one way to truncate the SVD of a given matrix

I want to understand what the code for the variable r does.

Attempt: They define a desired condition number for the matrix as kappanew = 1.e-5. The matrix S is the matrix of singular values which exist on the diagonal. To obtain a smaller condition number, then S must be truncated.
max(S(:)) grabs the largest singular value in S.  Multiplying it by kappanew scales it to be smaller. Then the find() locates the singular values larger than the new scaled value and then max() grabs the largest such value.
But why do we want to truncate at this index?

Notice the comment on the first line; truncating at this value lowers to condition number to at most $1/\kappa_{\text{new}}$

$r$ is the rank of the matrix after truncating the singular values.
